# Resetting ui: how?

Tags: android-layout, android

I have an activity with a UI with many elements (Radio, EditText, etc.). When I change the text in an EditText I want that UI back at its starting state.

I tried to kill and restart the activity but with poor results. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: setContentView is usually the proper way of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try calling `setContentView` again with a new view or with the xml file you used for rendering your activity in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You could add a listener to the EditText view and when the text is what you want it to be you can just programmatically empty any TextView's, EditText's, reset any radiobuttons or radio groups to their default values. No need to restart the activity. Just write a helper method that resets your view "manually". Using `setContentView()` could also work although I haven't tried it and you might have to setup your complete view again with listeners and such.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the value you need from your editText, you can reset it using

```
editText.setText("");
```

You can similarly programatically control other parts of your UI too.

Why not put all of the reset stuff in one function and simply call it when you need to:

```
public void resetUI()
{

//reset UI programatically

}
```

Comment: this was my first strategy.. but i have many items, so was boring reset all.. but ty for answer